# How to optimize a WordPress site with multiple sub-loops (sub-queries) to load faster

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to ask how to optimize or decrease queries for the WordPress site having multiple sub-loops to load the WordPress site faster.

■ Current situation

- Built a WordPress theme for real estate agency, and it has 150 housing posts as custom post type.
- The front page has five different sub-loops to show those housing posts according to their custom fields condition and custom taxonomies, such as "new", "contracted" (custom fields), "near sea", "traditional architecture"(custom taxonomies) and so on.
- Those multiple sub-loops slow down the website, especially for the user who visits for the first time.
- I checked the loading time with Chrome developer tool’s "Network" tab, and it takes over 7 seconds for Waiting (TTFB)
- When the sub-loops are commented out, the time drops to within 1 second, so definitely they slow down the website.

■ Question

- Is there any way I can optimize the multiple sub-loops?

■ Thoughts

- One solution is to get higher-spec web server, and the solution will be carried out too, but it may still need to optimize the codes
- pre_get_posts seems that they only work for main query, so maybe it can’t be a solution for this situation. (correct? )
- Loading all housing posts with one main query, and using loops conditionally seems a good solution, but it is very complicated to make conditional statements with those custom fields and custom taxonomies. (Reference: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-one-query-to-run-multiple-loops/)
- The below is an example sub-loop code

  ```
  <?php
       $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'real_estate',
              'taxonomy' => 're_category',
              'term' => 'sea',
              'orderby' => 'modified',
              'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                 'key' => 'show_top_sea',
                 'value' => '"show"',
                 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
              ),
            'no_found_rows' => true,
          );
     include locate_template( 'template/front-template.php' );
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Most likely those multiple sub loops are firing multiple queries. If true, this will require major refactoring and consolidation of queries into smaller number, eg using joins to fetch all of the data at once.

Comment: Thank you Madhur for your advice. I ended up using a main loop and push the data into an array, then separate the data conditionally. It improved the performance